# TextView to the right top of another TextView

Tags: android, textview, alignment, android-relativelayout

I would like to have a TextView (firstTextView) centered vertically and horizontally in a RelativeLayout, and have a second TextView (secondTextView) with its top-left corner matching the top-right corner of the firstTextView. Here my code:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:text="25"
            android:id="@+id/firstTextView"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:textSize="72sp"
            android:singleLine="false" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:text="°"
            android:id="@+id/secondTextView"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@id/currentTemp"
            />

</RelativeLayout>
```

The problem is that the second view is above the first view.

Comment: what is `android:layout_toEndOf="@id/currentTemp"` ??

Comment: @johntheripp3r it aligns the start/end edges. See my answer with link

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the property `android:layout_toRightOf="someID"`

```
<RelativeLayout
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="0dp"
android:layout_weight="1">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="25"
        android:id="@+id/firstTextView"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:textSize="72sp"
        android:singleLine="false" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:text="°"
        android:id="@+id/secondTextView"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/currentTemp"  // <-- Here 
        />
```

[According to the docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.html#END_OF) `toEndOf` is a

> Rule that aligns a child's start edge with another child's end edge.

So since `View`s in a `RelativeLayout` start at the top-left by default, the vertical position is not changed with this property.

Comment: Thanks, this worked for me. I also added layout_alignTop="@+id/firstTextView".

Comment: I wasn't paying attention to the `id`s you were using. `android:layout_toRightOf="@id/firstTextView"` should have worked also. Glad its working for you

Answer (score 0):

```
// try this
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="25"
        android:id="@+id/firstTextView"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:textSize="72sp"
        android:singleLine="false" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:text="°"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:layout_gravity="right|top"
        android:id="@+id/secondTextView"/>

</FrameLayout>
```